# Is there any way to reboot windows phone 8.1 using commands?Also is there any windows runtime API to restart the phone?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I am new to windows phone platform.Is there any commands or runtime API to restart windows phone 8.1?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good god, I hope not :P  That would be a very low system call or watchdog timer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no API that would allow you to do this.

As a general rule it could be said that there aren't any APIs that allow you to directly interfere with System/User settings or the function of the System or other Apps. Everything affecting settings/other Apps will go through some kind of launcher which allows the user to confirm the changes or perform the intended changes manually.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Can you explain that launcher thing a little detail?With that can we restart phone?

Comment: No, for reboots specifically there is no such Launcher. It was more a general statement on how this works on WP (e.g. there are Launchers to turn Wifi/Bluetooth/etc. on/off).